# CSS cannot seem to locate custom font

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx, fonts

Below is my CSS code and my file system:
My font file is in my /res/ folder, and that resides in my project folder.

`ProjectFolder/res/ExocetHeavy.tff`.

I looked at an online guide on how to put custom fonts in JavaFX with CSS and this is what I have:

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: gg;
    src: url("ExocetHeavy.ttf");
}
.label
{
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-font-family: gg;
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Note, if I try to surround `gg` with `' '` or `" "` in the `@font-face`, it claims that it is a `Invalid font family name`. Also one small annoyance is that every line of my CSS file in Eclipse is displayed as a warning in yellow (as seen below) which displays: `Unknown property: <line here>`, with `<line here>` being the content to the right of the `:`. If anyone knows how to fix that, let me know.

Anyways, does anyone know what I am doing wrong? My Labels are being affected correctly by `.label` as the font size changed, but the font does not.

[image: File System]

Comment: I don't see anything *wrong* in your css. Can you compare your project with [FontLoad](https://github.com/TheItachiUchiha/FontLoad) which I had created for assisting people when they can't load fonts :)

Comment: Odd, I'm having a really hard time getting your project to compile: http://i.imgur.com/4ablr3a.png

Comment: It is a maven project and you should use by importing it in eclipse as a maven project. I am not sure which eclipse version you are using, but you need to have a [maven plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) installed in eclipse. You can also run it from the terminal, instructions are already there.

Comment: Check your ttf is getting deployed correctly. It should be in the `bin` folder hierarchy (or whatever your output folder is configured to be), alongside the CSS file.

Comment: @James_D Yep, both there: http://i.imgur.com/EJ5saYR.png

Comment: Man I'm getting really frustrated: http://i.imgur.com/qGqAkid.png I tried it the JavaFX way and I'm still having problems. It doesn't cause a crash but the font is `null`. Which means it SEES the font but somehow doesn't load it properly. This font is proper and I can even upload it here if you guys would want.

Comment: @Hatefiend Have you tried to put `@font-face` declaration at the top of the css file. In my experience it doesn't work if it is not declared at the beginning of the css file.

Comment: Okay so I think I've solved it (so dumb how I had to do it). I got the idea from this image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-biUlpdszNJ8/USxKY8rO51I/AAAAAAAABkw/aMXV_rfI2v0/s1600/JavaFX_Font_loadFont.png. I went into Eclipse and, even though my source was being seen, I made a new `Fonts` folder and linked DIRECTLY to that folder. Right click `ProjectNameHere` -> `Build Path` -> `Link Source`. Then I did: `Font myFont = Font.loadFont(GUI.class.getResourceAsStream("/Exocet.ttf"), 16);` and it worked. Really upsetting but oh well, it works.

Comment: Does the font load works from css as well?

Comment: I haven't tested it but I'd presume no. I'll give it a shot later though.